# Pointing my domain name to my ubuntu web server

Tags: networking, domain-server

I am very new at this so forgive me if i sound ignorant.

I have been trying to build a web server using ubuntu 18.04 lts. I have installed the lamp stack, did port forwarding on my router (80 and 8080) and I am able to access my server from anywhere using the ip address. I tried to use my domain name to link to my server by adding the server's ip address to my A-record but it won't work.

The ip address is 192.168.0.9 and you will see that it works using the ip address and the domain name is www.familyseekers.net and this one won't work.

Any input will be greatly appreciated and if you guys can direct me to a good tutorial on the subject, it will also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The IP address you mentioned is an internal address, used by your home network. Are you sure you can reach to your server from outside your office/house?

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses in the 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255 range are internal addresses (private use). They are not reachable from the internet. Moreover, many DNS server will, by default, explicitly ignore responses containing these internal addresses.

Finally, you'll need to ensure that [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) or NAT loopback is setup on the router where you've configured the port forwarding.